# How can I set the icons according to the specifications?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

How can I set the icons according to the specifications?

specifications:
http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

```
<Grid>
        <maps:CustomMap HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End">
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="ic_profile.png" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding CurrentPoints}" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="ic_message.png" />
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="ic_settings.png" VerticalOptions="End" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Source="ic_time.png" VerticalOptions="Start" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Source="ic_center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Source="ic_profile.png" VerticalOptions="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi @Piotr your url is broken, please check it

Comment: I fixed it. Thank You